# Use index.html as welcome page

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a simple java application. I want to set index.html as my welcome page.

I tried it but its not working. Although index.jsp is working. 
Is it possible to use index.html?

```
<display-name>sample</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>    
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: It is very much possible to your index.html. What directory your index.html stored?

Comment: It is under webContent folder of my Dynamic Web Project. When I use index.html, I get 404 error

Answer (score 1):

Update your web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list> 
 <welcome-file>webContent/index.html</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list>
```

You are getting 404 - Page not found because you cannot access files under WEB-INF folder directly

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is because of the servlet mapping you are doing.

You should change `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>` to something different so that there is no diffusion.

Comment: I tried following but still same error. <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>