# Why Spring doesn't load index.html as welcome file

Tags: java, jsp

My Spring project doesn't load with index.html as welcome file but if I rename it to `index.jsp` then it works fine. Why?

My `web.xml`

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

[image: page with index.html as welcome file]

If I changes index.html to index.jsp, page seems to be loading.

[image: page with index.jsp as welcome file]

I have seen other question like this but with no correct answers. [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752171/use-index-html-as-welcome-page)

Comment: Please dont remove the tags as I want tag experts to see this question and answer. Thanks.

Comment: Please understand that Spring is **completely irrelevant** for this. The *problem* is related to Java Web Applications only, despite if you use Spring MVC or any other web MVC framework like Struts 2, Vaadin, JSF or another.

Comment: I agree with you but I would to like to reach to maximum audience. Thank you.

Comment: Then you're improperly using the tags and just making noise in proper questions of those tags.

Comment: You are a better person and in better position to say on this, so I will remove the tags. But I request you to reach out to someone who can help me on this. I appreciate your inputs. Thanks.

Comment: Spring is mapped to `*.html` so it tries to deal with your request. You presumably have no mapping in Spring for dealing with this so the spring servlet returns a 404. In the second case, `*.jsp` is not mapped to Spring to the application server serves the jsp as requested.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I will try playing with it to see how things work with different mapping.

Comment: You can find your answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670327/welcome-file-not-working-with-html-file-in-spring

Comment: You can find your answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670327/welcome-file-not-working-with-html-file-in-spring